# Silverlight call from aspx no longer working

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I'm fixing up some old code that uses silverlight along with arcgis.  The silverlight portion broke over time.  The code that's originally used is:

```
<asp:Silverlight ID="xamlMain" runat="server" Source="ClientBin/ControlPoints.xap" MinimumVersion="3.0.40624.0" Width="100%" Height="100%" />
```

and the way it was called

```
function RefreshControlPointLayer() {
    var slControl = document.getElementById("xamlMain");
    slControl.Content.RefreshControlPointsLayer();
    }
```

I would get "slControl.Control is undefined." After looking up the silverlight call (I have no prior experience or knowledge of silverlight) I found that the way it's being called is old, so I changed it to the new object way.

```
<object type="application/x-silverlight-2" data="data:application/x-silverlight," width="100%" height="100%">
                    <param name="source" value="ClientBin/ControlPoints.xap" />
                    <param name="id" value="xamlMain" />
                    <param name="runat" value="server" />
                    <param name="onError" value="onSiliverError" />
                    <param name="background" value="white" />
                    <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40624.0" />
                    <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
                    <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.60310.0" style="text-decoration:none">
                     <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
                    </a>
                </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style='visibility: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px; border: 0px'></iframe>
```

and I call it by just calling the function "RefreshControlPointsLayer()."  In chrome's inspector console I'm able to see this code

```
function refreshControlPointsLayer() {      
    window.opener.RefreshControlPointLayer();
    return false;
}
```

but in firebug all I can is

```
<td align="center">
<span id="ctl00_Main_gv_import_ctl21_ImportStatus" disabled="disabled"      style="color:Red;"></span>
</td><td>10X</td><td>5570.47000</td><td>1244.33900</td><td>473.69900</td><td>BRK-10X bk 25596 pg ?? </td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

The function refreshControlPointsLayer() doesn't even show up in firebug.  But both tell me "window.opener.refreshControlPointsLayer is not a function." I've opened the xap file but all it contained was dll's.

Am I calling the silverlight object wrong?  Has anyone ever had anything similar happen to them? Would any one off the top of there head know how I should properly call a xap file from an aspx page so I can use it's functions? thank you for any help.